# if XML file is not there return an error XML

Tags: php, xml

i'm reading a xml file in php. but if the file is not found i need to return a xml file with an error message. Following is the code of the php. when the file is not there it doen't return a xml and gives a error

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
$url = '../../data/customer.xml';
if (file_exists($url)) 
{
$xmlDoc->load($url);
echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
$strXml = $xmlDoc->saveXML(); 
return $strXml;
 }
 else
 { //trying to create a error xml
    $cart = $xmlDoc->createElement('cart');
    $cart = $xmlDoc->appendChild($cart);
    $strXml = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
return $strXml;
}
```

thanx in advance

Comment: XML Parsing Error : junk after document element.

Comment: Here is no output (echo, print, ...) in the code. Try disabling the header.